# AWS lightsail Loadbalencer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail, amazon-elb

I have **server-1** with node js and MongoDB installed, And I created **server-2** from the snapshot of **server-1** and I have created a load balancer and attached both servers,
My question here is does MongoDB is copied each other suppose if server-2 goes down and all the traffic will be to **Server-1** right, Once when **server-2** is up the **database** content will be different between 2 servers right?

Answer (score 1):

The database content will be different as soon as the next insert or update happens, since the load will be balanced between the two servers, each server will get 50% of the requests, so each server will have 50% of the changes on their own database.

You can't run MongoDB on each server like this in a load balanced environment. You would need to run MongoDB on a separate server that both NodeJS servers connect to.